# Induced matrix p-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\|\cdot\|_p$ denote the $p$ norm $(p≥1)$ defined for every vector $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^t\in\mathbb C^n$ by $\|x\|_p=(\sum|x_j|^p)^{1/p}$ and let $|||\cdot|||_p$ denote the matrix norm defined for every $n\times n$ matrix $A$ by $|||A|||_p=\max\{\|Ax\|_p:x\in\mathbb C^n,\|x\|_p=1\}.$

It is known that the $|||⋅|||_{p}$ can be computed explicitly in terms of the entries of the matrix in the cases $p=1,p→∞$ and can also easily computed for $2×2$ matrices in the case $p=2$. My question is, can we write a general formula for $|||⋅|||_{p}$ of $2×2$ matrices or even for upper triangular $2×2$ matrices?

Comment: Maybe using SVD reveals something? I'm not sure though.

Comment: The optimization problem seems very hard to perform analytically for general $p$. The equations we need to solve are on the form $(a + bx^{p-1}(1-x^p)^{1/p-1})(cx+d(1-x^p)^{1/p})^{p-1} + \ldots = 0$ which does not look very solvable.

Comment: Your claim at the beginning of the second paragraph is wrong. Since polynomials of degrees 5 or above are in general not solvable by radicals, the induced 2-norm of $A$ in general cannot be expressed explicitly in terms of the entries of $A$ when $n\ge5$.

Comment: I don't understand why finding the $p$ norm is equivalent to solving a polynomial of degree $n>4$. Note that when $p→∞$ then the norm is the maximum absolute row sum, which can be easily computed.